# how can I compare values of list with the function values by only using the if condition in python?

Tags: python

here is my code and I'm not getting the logic, how can I Compare them.
so that;
If the value doesn't exist already, it should be added and the function should return True. If the value does exist, it should not be added, and the function should return False;

```
 myUniqueList = [1,2,3]
 myLeftovers  = [] 

def Values_List (value) :
    myUniqueList.append(value)
    if value == [value]:
       print (False)
    else:
        print (True)
    print (myUniqueList)

print (myUniqueList)
Values_List(2)
```

Comment: Is it printing `True` always?

Comment: yes its only printing true!

Comment: That is because `value == [value]` always false

Comment: Why you are not using `numpy.unique`?

Comment: @Ahx Because it would raise a NameError?

Comment: Use it `print(numpy.unique(myUniqueList))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may code exactly what you explained

```
def Values_List(value):
    if value in myUniqueList:   # if value already in the list
        return False            # return False
    myUniqueList.append(value)  # else add it to the list
    return True                 # and return True

myUniqueList = [1, 3]
print(myUniqueList)    # [1, 3]
print(Values_List(2))  # True
print(myUniqueList)    # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with  this "in" keyword.
please can you explain it to me, that'll be great!

Comment: @Random_Guy it pretty straight-forward `a in listB` is a boolean expression that results in True is element `a` is **IN** the list `listB` and False, if it isn't

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Random_Guy You can now think about accepting the answer to reward it (green tick on the left ot it)

Comment: sorry I didn't knew, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

```py
def Values_List (value) :
    if value not in myUniqueList:
        myUniqueList.append(value)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Did you really think this through and test it?

Comment: `if value in [value]` did you read that ? ;)

Comment: I didn't actually, just focused on the appending part. I have updated, apologies @ekhumoro

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
myUniqueList = [1,2,3]

def Values_List (value) :
    if value not in myUniqueList:
        myUniqueList.append(value)  
    print (myUniqueList)

print (myUniqueList)
Values_List(2)
```